# Google DFP custom parameters

Tags: reactjs, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I am working on a ReactJS app which currently uses the [react-gpt](https://github.com/nfl/react-gpt)  module to serve DFP ads.

Is it possible to create a DFP ad that displays custom HTML & CSS that we pass into it? I want to create a “native ad” experience where the ad content is managed by the application’s content (title, image path, content teaser) & use a content id to connect it to DFP to manage performance.

If anything is unclear, please let me know. I’ve been searching the documentation & have not found an example of what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Could you plz clarify at what stage do you need to 'pass' HTML & CSS into it?

Comment: When the page loads, it contains content related data that we want to use to build the ad.  I want to send this data to DPF to create a custom ad experience.